# How to send back a json datatype

Tags: javascript, json, vert.x

i'm using a vert.x server with a small javascript code as follow:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        data: {id:content},
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data) {alert("succes")+data;})
    .fail(function() { alert("fail");})
    .always(function() { alert("complete");});
```

When i run my program, i have the alert("succes") popup (which mean i did my post and have answer in return right ?)  but the variable data is empty. In my java code i'm doing this to send an answer:

```
request.response().putHeader("content-type", "json")
            .end(Json.encodePrettily(content));
```

Where content is just a string with what i post on the server with the POST request.
If i have response of my server, why the data field of my js code is still empty ?
Am i doing this wrong ?

Comment: The correct content type for JSON is `application/json`. How do you check the response? You just concatenate the returned value of an `alert` call which is `undefined` with the request's response and don't do anything with the returned value.

Comment: ... Check the browser's network tab for debugging Ajax requests or log the  variable by using the `console.log` function. `alert` is not a good option for debugging.

Comment: When i replace the json by application/json, it answers me "fail". Is thios normal ?

Comment: That means jQuery can't parse the response as JSON and subsequently `fail` handler is called.

Comment: So the problem comes from the datas sent from my server ?

Comment: Yes. However, that's just one of the reasons that a request which expects JSON as response fails. Try `$.parseJSON('invalidJSON')` and see that it throws an error.

Comment: i don't understand where i should use the parseJSON, (i'm very new to jquery)

Comment: As a suggestion, always read the documentations of a tool/library that you are using. This can save you lots of time and prevent headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your alert to this:

```
alert("success \n" + JSON.stringify(data));
```